# How to reconnect to an existing Jupyter notebook session in VS code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I remember I was able to reconnect to an existing Jupyter Notebook session in VS code before by changing the kernel for a notebook. Now the option to reconnect to an existing session is gone, see:

[image: change kernel menu]

How do I reconnect to an existing Jupyter Notebook session in VS code?

To be clear, the sessions were never shut down. In fact, I can still see them running in the **Running** tab of my browser version of Jupyter Notebook, although clicking on them results in a 404 error:

[image: jupyter notebook Running tab]

The Jupyter kernel is running on a remote server. I use an SSH session to connect back to it when I work.

Current versions: VS code is v1.68.1 and the Jupyter extension on the remote machine is v2022.5.1001601848, if that helps.

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/186903

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you would like to connect to an existing jupyter server can you do so by going into the command `Jupyter: Specify Jupyter Server for Connections` and selecting the appropriate remote server from the list. If the required server is not on that list, then you can select it.

Comment: Just saw this answer searching for the similar problem. However for me this command "Jupyter: Specify Jupyter Server for Connections" is simply not shown in command palette (I have all the related plugins installed). Do you know why could it be the case?

Comment: Same here, as @demitau mentioned. I thought that the "Specify Jupyter Server for Connections" option would come from the official Jupyter vscode extension. 

environment
Jupyter v2023.6.1101941928
vscode: Version: 1.80.1 (Universal)

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot see the command **Jupyter: Specify Jupyter Server for Connections**

You can follow the steps:

**Select Kernel -> Select Another Kernel... -> Existing Jupyter Server... -> Enter the URL of the running Jupyter server**

Comment: I have tried this; it only sometimes works. But sometimes it just doesn't show the existing kernels. The problem is not specifying the server URL; it's specifying the kernel ID for that server.